# How to Import dozens of svg file in vue/nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am currently importing alot of svg files using the normal import statement like the following.

index.vue

```
<script>
import danalock from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_danalock.svg"
import smartlock from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_smart-lock.svg"
import light from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_light.svg"
import clicker from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_clicker.svg"
import battery100 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-100.svg"
import environmental from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_environmental.svg"
import batter25charge from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-25_charge.svg"
import doorWindow from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_door-window.svg"
import battery50 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-50.svg"
import motion from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_motion.svg"
import battery75 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-75.svg"
import airConditioner from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_air-cononditioner.svg"
import tv from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_tv.svg"
import fan from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_fan.svg"
import airCleaner from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_air-cleaner.svg"
import mediaPlayer from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_media-player.svg"
import speaker from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_speaker.svg"
import remoteController from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_remote-controller.svg"

export default {
  components: {
    danalock,
    smartlock,
    light,
    clicker,
    battery100,
    environmental,
    batter25charge,
    ...
  },
```

I already searching for some workarounds like making a folder in components like components/images/ and made an image.js and put all the import statement there like the following

components/images/images.js

```
import danalock from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_danalock.svg"
import smartlock from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_smart-lock.svg"
import light from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_light.svg"
import clicker from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_clicker.svg"
import battery100 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-100.svg"
import environmental from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_environmental.svg"
import batter25charge from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-25_charge.svg"
import doorWindow from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_door-window.svg"
import battery50 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-50.svg"
import motion from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_motion.svg"
import battery75 from "~/assets/img/smarthome/icon-battery-75.svg"
import airConditioner from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_air-cononditioner.svg"
import tv from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_tv.svg"
import fan from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_fan.svg"
import airCleaner from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_air-cleaner.svg"
import mediaPlayer from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_media-player.svg"
import speaker from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_speaker.svg"
import remoteController from "~/assets/img/smarthome/list-icon_remote-controller.svg"


export default {
  danalock,
  smartlock,
  light,
  clicker,
  ...
}
```

and tried accessing it in my vue file like the follow but can't find good results

index.vue

```
<script>
import { danalock, smartlock } from "~/components/images/images.js"

export default {
  components: {
    danalock,
    smartlock,
    ...
  }
```

the template of my index.vue

```
<template>
  <smartlock />
</template>
```

throws the following error

```
Unknown custom element: <smartlock> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Comment: *but can't find good results* - does this mean there are errors?

Comment: I added the error in the explanation thanks !

Comment: ao, vuejs is supposed to import svg's as *components*?

Comment: that is how I am currently using it. when you use it as components it is just like an img tag

Comment: oh, that works for you? I must be doing it wrong